# StackOverflow Exception when notifying RelayCommand of CanExecuteChanged using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-community-toolkit

I'm implementing the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm framework on my WPF desktop application. I'm using the in-built RelayCommand with the 'CanExecute' coming from a navigation service helper class that I've written elsewhere.

Very simply I want the Button which is bound to the RelayCommand to update the CanExecute boolean when the navigation service is used to switch between views. On trying to raise the `Command.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();` method, I am getting a `System.StackOverflowException` on loading the view?

```
public MainViewModel() {
   _navigationServices = new NavigationServices();
   this.PreviousViewCommand = new RelayCommand(this.PreviousViewModel, CanNavigate);
}

private void PreviousViewModel() {
   this.CurrentPageViewModel = _navigationServices.GetPreviousView();
}

private bool CanNavigate() {
   this.PreviousViewCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged(); /// it is here where the StackOverflow Exception is being thrown
   return _navigationService.CanNavigate;
}
```

Navigation in WPF MVVM is a bit of a pain, but this seems like an easy piece of data binding between a button, command and the `CanExecute`. Can someone help me in finding what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What calling `NotifyCanExecuteChanged` does is telling every control that is bound to the command to call the `CanExecute` method of the command... which in this case then calls its `NotifyCanExecuteChanged` method, which calls the `CanExecute` method and so on, which is why you get the `StackOverflowException`.

> I want the Button which is bound to the RelayCommand to update the CanExecute boolean when the navigation service is used to switch between views

I believe what you want to achieve can be done by simply calling `this.PreviousViewCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged()` whenever the views have been switched. That should suffice; either way, don't call the `NotifyCanExecuteChanged` method of a command in its own `CanExecute` method.